# Как инкапсулировать логику в один метод

Tags: c#, ооп, solid

Я реализую задачу ["Дилемма заключённого"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE).

В "итерационной" версии (т.е. в которой имеется более, чем одно преступление, в котором обвиняются заключённые), их действия зависят или не зависят (в зависимости от выбранной стратегии) от предыдущего решения оппонента и года суммируются.

Я создал абстрактный класс для стратегии:

```
public abstract class StrategyBase
{
    public string StrategyName { get; set; }
    public abstract Action Init();
    public abstract Action Next(Action previousActionOfAnotherPrisoner);
}

public enum Action
{
    Tie = 0,
    Informer = 1
}
```

класс заключённого:

```
public class Prisoner 
{
    public string PrisonerName { get; private set; }
    public StrategyBase Strategy { get; private set; }
    public Action? LastAction { get; private set; }
    public int TotalYears { get; private set; }

    public Prisoner(string name, StrategyBase strategy)
    {
        if (strategy == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("strategy");

        PrisonerName = name;
        Strategy = strategy;
    }

    public void Do(Action? previousActionOfAnotherPrisoner)
    {
        if (previousActionOfAnotherPrisoner == null)
            LastAction = Strategy.Init();
        else
            LastAction = Strategy.Next(previousActionOfAnotherPrisoner.Value);
    }

    public void AddYears(ConvictionYears years)
    {
        TotalYears += (int)years;
    }
}
```

Далее класс Дилемма это всё вызывает:

```
public class Dilemma
{
    private Prisoner prisoner1;
    private Prisoner prisoner2;

    public Dilemma(Prisoner prisoner1, Prisoner prisoner2)
    {
        if (prisoner1 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("prisoner1");

        if (prisoner2 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("prisoner2");


        this.prisoner1 = prisoner1;
        this.prisoner2 = prisoner2;
    }

    public IterationInfo Iteration()
    {
        Action? previousAction1 = prisoner1.LastAction;
        Action? previousAction2 = prisoner2.LastAction;

        prisoner1.Do(previousAction2);
        prisoner2.Do(previousAction1);

        Utils.AddYears(prisoner1, prisoner2);

        return new IterationInfo(prisoner1.LastAction.Value, prisoner2.LastAction.Value, prisoner1.TotalYears, prisoner2.TotalYears);
    }

}
```

Это всё чудесно работает. Но мне не нравится один момент - начисление лет. Т.к. их начисление для каждого зависит от решения второго заключённого, я не могу эту логику засунуть в Do, а вынужден разнести по 2-м методам. и вызывать их из вызывающего класса Dilemma последовательно (в данном случае логика сколько лет дадут тому или другому инкапсулирована в Utils.AddYears()). Мне не нравится, что клиент должен "не забыть" вызвать AddYears. По сути, это всё должно быть в одном действии. Как такое правильно реализовать? В методе Do устанавливать временную переменную и городить логику проверок?

Comment: Кто кроме `Dilemma` обращается к классу `Prisoner`? Может, стоит передавать дилемме не заключенных, а их стратегии, а самих заключенных сделать полностью внутренними классами?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не пойму, что мне это даст в таком случае.

Comment: Это сделает методы Do и AddYears не внешними - а внутренними.

Comment: А как их тогда вызывать? Можете пример накидать, а то я что-то не пойму? :)